# Using Shims: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, twilio, shim

I am using a shim as follows:

```
ShimTwilioRestClient.AllInstances.SendSmsMessageStringStringString =
(@this, num, to, msg) =>
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(msg);
};
```

But the first line gives me this error:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression  of type
>   `Fakes.FakesDelegates.Func<TwilioReselientClient, String, String, String, SMSMessage>`

Comment: The question is what did i do wrong? why am i having this error

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the `SendSmsMessageStringStringString` property is meant to be a delegate which returns an `SmsMessage`... but you're not returning anything.

You *may* just be able to get away with:

```
ShimTwilioRestClient.AllInstances.SendSmsMessageStringStringString =
(@this, num, to, msg) =>
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(msg);
    return null;
};
```

... it depends on what's going to happen to the return value.